# Blazor Server - Cannot read properties of null (reading addEventListener)

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

In Blazor Server, I've created a div and made it essentially the size of my page; I want to test that, through an event listener in my javascript file, I can send an alert when the div is clicked. I've added my js file link in _Layout.cshtml:

```html
<head>
    <!-- Other code -->
    <script src="~/js/common.js"></script>
    <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

My javascript file:

```js
document.getElementById('scanner-page').addEventListener('click', touchHandler, true);

function touchHandler(e) {
    if (e.type == "click") {
        alert("You clicked!");
    }
}
```

And on my Blazor component, I have my div with height, width, etc. on a StyleSheet.css file:

Blazor Component:

```html
<div id="scanner-page">
    <!-- Other code here -->
</div>
```

StyleSheet.css:

```css
#scanner-page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But when running my page, I'm getting the following error, pointed right at my event listener:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading addEventListener).

My first thought was that the javascript file was being loaded too late, but now I'm not sure; maybe there is an error in my syntax somewhere? I've checked my ID on the component side and it seems to match what I have in the javascript, so I'm not really sure why my code is returning null for that ID.

**UPDATE**:

Per sschwei1, I added the following code and while the null error is gone, the alert does not seem to be triggered at all.

```js
document.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('scanner-page').addEventListener('click', touchHandler, true);
}

function touchHandler(e) {
    if (e.type == "click") {
        alert("You clicked!");
    }
}
```

Comment: add the `defer` keyword in your script tag `<script src="~/js/common.js" defer></script>`

Comment: the problem is, your js code is executed, before the dom is rendered, so `.getElementById(...)` returns `null`, `defer` will make it so your js will be executed, after your page is loaded

Comment: you could also use `document.onload = (evt) => {...}` or `window.onload = (evt) => {...}` and call your code inside there, this event is fired, when the page finished loading, so again your element exists and you can add the eventListener

Comment: Hi @sschwei1, I added your suggestion for both defer and the document.onload function, and while the null error seems to be gone, I'm not getting any alert when I click on the page. I've edited my post to show my new code.

Comment: try to add a `console.log(...)` before your `if(e.type == 'click')` and see if the function is called in the first place, i just tried your code in a test environment and it worked fine for me

Comment: also try adding a background color to your element, it could be that `height: 100%` will leave the element at 0px height, so it is never clicked

Answer (score 1):

You're current problem is timing the assignment of event to the lifecycle of the `div`, i.e. it's existence in the DOM.

You can call a JsFunction from `OnAfterEnder` to assign the handler when the element exists.

But there's a simpler way: set up the `onclick` event directly in the component.  I've assigned it in `MainLayout` so it captures a click anywhere on the page.

Once captured, you can do whatever you want.  I just do a simple bit of JsInterop similar to yours, that I can include in a one page demo to keep things simple.

#### MainLayout.razor

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IJSRuntime js;
<PageTitle>SO75438382</PageTitle>

<div class="page" @onclick=this.PageClicked>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

@code {

    private async Task PageClicked()
    {
        // can call C# stuff or make a call to a js function
        bool confirm = await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Hello");
    }
}
```

Note: There will be propagation issues with clicking on say buttons and links.